# Can I compile a forward declaration from C to WebAssembly with Emscripten?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I have C code like this (grossly simplified to illustrate the idea):

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

void some_function(int32_t some_argument);

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE my_function(int32_t arg1, int32_t arg2)
{
   some_function(arg1);
   some_function(arg2);
}
```

I would like to compile this to WebAssembly, with the idea that the forward declaration of `some_function` gets turned into a WebAssembly import, for the Embedder to provide.

I invoke emscripten with `emcc --no-entry -O3 -o mywasm.wasm mycode.c`, but it complains that `some_function` wasn't found: `wasm-ld: error: undefined symbol: some_function`.

It does make sense because there is no function body - but that's the point: I want that function body to be provided at runtime by the Embedder of the WebAssembly module.

I've checked the [documentation for emscripten.h](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html) for anything useful, but couldn't find anything that says "make this a required WebAssembly import".

Is there a way to achieve this through emscripten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to pass `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` to the emcc call.

The generated wasm will then just have an import for it: `(import "env" "some_function" (func $env.some_function (type $t3)))`

Providing that function from the Embedder makes it all work perfectly fine.